# How can i solve this kibana console error

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

[image]

Anytime I run kibana and host it on the web I get above error

Comment: seems like kibana can't access some ressources on your elasticsearch cluster!

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you have enabled the role based access and not provided the access to the user who is trying to login here.

You need to add user to the Kibana to be allowed to access the kibana.